# How to make Microsoft Windows 7 Search display the actual Folder Location instead of some cryptic path?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-explorer, search

I am very dissatisfied with the search offered by Windows 7 Explorer. Let me first explain what happens, and what I expect:

- I have a folder c:\test. When I use explorer-search and search for *test*, that folder is found.
- When I doubleclick that found folder, the contents of the folders are opened, but windows explorer does not display c:\test in the address bar. Instead, it displays some strange folder that is unusable to other programs like "Search Results\test".
- To get the behaviour I want to get, I have to right-click the found folder and select "Open Folder Location", which is what I'd actuallly expect to get when I doubleclick the folder.

How can I make that expected behaviour the default behaviour, and why has Microsoft implemented that this way? It used to be all okay in Windows XP, but is totally messed up in Win7 :(

Comment: Try using [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/). It's much faster at searching and it opens folders in their correct paths

Comment: I like Everything, but it does not work on network shares. Besides, it is easier to have such a feature in explorer, and I wonder why the explorer-based search is getting worse with every Windows-version :(